# Cassandra: Adding new denormalized query tables for existing keyspace/data

Tags: cassandra, denormalization

From the beginning of an application, you plan ahead and denormalize data at write-time for faster queries at read-time. Using Cassandra "BATCH" commands, you can ensure atomic updates across multiple tables.

But, what about when you add a new feature, and need a new denormalized table? Do you need to run a temporary script to populate this new table with data? Is this how people normally do it? Is there a feature in Cassandra that will do this for me?

Comment: Probably going to have a run an update script to populate it.

Comment: @tymeJV But I don't want too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet hence the new answer.  The answer is yes, you'd have to write a migration script and run that when you deploy your software upgrade with the new feature.  That's fairly a typical devops release process from my experience.

I've not seen anything like Code First Migrations (for MS SQL Server & Entity Framework) for Cassandra, which does the migration script automatically for you.

Comment: This is perfectly fine as an answer